# How to search for categories based on their products name and price using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity called Category and another called Product. Each category can have multiple products. I have a search form to search for categories. The form has three fields, category, product and price. If user enters category name it shows that category if name of product is selected the category of that product will be shown and if price is selected those categories that their products have the selected price will be shown.

I suppose I should have two criteria statements, one to find search based on categories name and the other to find categories of products that their name or price match the criteria but I am wondering if there is any other more efficient method to do it?

```
if(search field category name is provided)
    search for all categories that their name is matched with the provided text
    add the found categories to the list of results
if(search fields product name and/or price are provided)
    search for category of matched products and matched category name if the category name is provided
    add the found categories to the list of results

return the results list
```

**Entities**

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue 
  private long id;
  private long name;

  getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue 
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private float price;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category")
  private Category category;

  getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the map interface.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

It allows you to set up a map of keys and values. You could assign certain products to certain key values. I don't know if this answers your question, but it's a thought.